# Sum the same cell from multiple sheets in Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Which is the ideal script to sum the same cell across the sheets in Google Sheets?
For example, I need to sum the A1 cells of fifty progressive sheets
`=sum(‘Sheet0’!A1 + ‘Sheet2’!A1 + ‘Sheet’!A1 and so on)`
and I would like to do it more efficiently than writing every single sheet name, as well as in excel
`=sum(Sheet0:Sheet50!A1)`

Answer (score 0):

#### Sum A1 of matching sheets

```
function sheetcellsum() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  let sum = 0;
  ss.getSheets().forEach(sh => {
    if(sh.getName().match(/Sheet\d+/)) {
      sum += sh.getRange('A1').getValue();
    }
  });
  //Logger.log(sum);
  return sum;
}
```

[getSheets()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getSheets())

Answer (score 0):

```
=sum(map(sequence(51), lambda(x, indirect("Sheet"&(x-1)&"!A1"))))
```

This will add the cell A1 values from Sheet0 .. Sheet50 (i.e., 51 sheets).
If you actually wanted just Sheet1 through Sheet50, change 51 to 50, and (x-1) to x.

Google has added some common functional programming features including map and anonymous lambda, nicely explained here:
https://www.benlcollins.com/spreadsheets/new-functions-in-google-sheets-2022/

The only other thing of interest is that "indirect()" function which is used to construct cell references from strings.